# php and snmp strange behavior

Tags: php, snmp

I'm trying to send a snmp request via php and I'm experiencing some problems by using snmpget. In bash shell everything works fine, in php with snmpget I get some errors and with shell_exec not, and vice versa (see Source Code).

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
snmp_read_mib('/home/user/.snmp/mibs/PDU2-MIB.txt');
snmp_read_mib('/home/user/.snmp/mibs/ASSETMANAGEMENT-MIB.txt');

echo $output = shell_exec("snmpget -v 2c -c public 192.168.1.58 .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.31.3.1.6.2.3");
//correct output
echo "<br>";
echo snmpget("192.168.1.58", "public", ".1.3.6.1.2.1.4.31.3.1.6.2.3");
//Warning: snmpget(): Error in packet at 'RFC1213-MIB::ip.31.3.1.6.2.3': (noSuchname)


echo $output = shell_exec("snmpget -v 2c -c public -m +ASSETMANAGEMENT-MIB:PDU2-MIB 192.168.1.58 PDU2-MIB::newestLogID.1");
//no output at all - in bash I get the correct value/output
echo "<br>";
echo snmpget("192.168.1.58", "public", "PDU2-MIB::newestLogID.1");
//correct output
```

It seems that numerical OIDs are only working with shell_exec and Alias-OIDs only work with the function snmpget().

Why is that? Is it not possible to use snmpget with own mibs and numerical oids? 
And why don't I even get a response by my second shell_exec when it is working perfectly in the bash? (not even an error message with error_reporting on)..

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you try to get 64 bit counter variable (IP-MIB::ipIfStatsHCInOctets.ipv6.3) only available in snmp v2 or v3 using snmpget function.
Use snmp2_get(); function instead. Parameters are same as snmpget();

See comment in docs: [snmpget function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.snmpget.php)